# How do we further simplify this expression involving a complex number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I will state the problem here:

Let $\omega$ be a complex number such that $\omega^5 = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1$. Compute
$\frac{\omega}{1 + \omega^2} + \frac{\omega^2}{1 + \omega^4} + \frac{\omega^3}{1 + \omega} + \frac{\omega^4}{1 + \omega^3}.$

W is obviously a complex number. I've tried arranging and rearranging the terms in a way to further simplify the expression, but I'm having trouble getting anywhere with it. Anyone have ideas on how to proceed and solve the problem?

Comment: Use the given condition to get $ω^4 = 1/ω$ and edit your question to include what you can get from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and last terms are equal, as can be seen by multiplying the latter's numerator and denominator by $\omega^2$. A similar treatment, with a factor of $\omega$, shows the middle terms are equal too. So we want to double$$\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}+\frac{\omega^3}{1+\omega}=\frac{\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^5}{(1+\omega)(1+\omega^2)}=1,$$giving $2$ as the final answer. We actually don't need to exclude $\omega=1$ for this to work.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Before I posted here, I managed to find that the first and last terms were equal, and the middle two terms were equal as well. I wasn't sure how to move on from there.